# How can I replicate Python's dict.items() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, associative-array

In Javascript I have a JSON object from which I want to process just the items:

```
var json = {
    itema: {stuff: 'stuff'},
    itemb: {stuff: 'stuff'},
    itemc: {stuff: 'stuff'},
    itemd: {stuff: 'stuff'}
}
```

In Python I could do

```
print json.items()
[{stuff: 'stuff'},{stuff: 'stuff'},{stuff: 'stuff'},{stuff: 'stuff'}]
```

Can I do this is js?

Comment: I should probably add that the _reason_ I want to do that is so that I can then sort the array (the keys are just uids), so maybe I should have asked "how to sort the items in an associativ array".

Comment: The question is incorrect. Python's `dict.items()` returns a list of (key,value) tuples. Your example of retval corresponds to `dict.values()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this the same way as in python without extending Object.prototype, which you don't want to do, because it is the path to misery.

You could create a helper function easily that could loop over the object and put the value into an array however, like this:

```
function items(obj) {
 var i, arr = [];
 for(i in obj) {
   arr.push(obj[i]);
 }
 return arr;
}
```

Ps: JSON is a data format, what you have is an object literal.

Comment: Point taken about the object literal, they're so closely connected in js that you might forgive me on that one.

Answer (score 4):

In python `dict.items` returns a list of tuples containing both the keys and the values of the `dict`. Javascript doesn't have tuples, so it would have to be a nested array.

If you'll excuse me a little python code to show the difference.

```
>>> {1:2, 2:3}.items()
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> {1:2, 2:3}.values()
[2, 3]
```

I see the accepted answer returns an array of the objects values, which is the equivalent of the python function `dict.values`. What is asked for is `dict.items`. To do this just loop and build up a nested array of 2 element arrays.

```
function items(obj){

    var ret = [];
    for(v in obj){
        ret.push(Object.freeze([v, obj[v]]));
    }
    return Object.freeze(ret);
}
```

I put the `Object.freeze` in to be pedantic and enforce that the returned value shouldn't be altered, to emulate the immutability of python tuples. Obviously it still works if you take it out.

It should be noted that doing this somewhat defeats the purpose of `items` in that it is used when iterating over the object in a linear rather than associative fashion and it avoids calculating the hash value to look up each element in the associative array. For small objects who cares but for large ones it might slow you down and there might be a more idiomatic way to do what you want in javascript.

Another newer way to do it is to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) which will do exactly what you want.

```
Object.entries({1:1, 2:2, 3:3})
      .forEach(function(v){
          console.log(v)
      });
```

The support is limited to those browser versions mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: You should drop that `.hasOwnProperty()` call. There's no advantage.

Comment: No, just that's it's pretty pointless in there. What's the condition good for? The usual objects you want to enumerate won't have inherited enumerable properties. And if you want to defend against those that have, you surely want to defend against those that have `.hasOwnProperty` properties as well.

Comment: oh ok thanks. I though it would exclude any properties from a parent class. I'm a relative noob at javascript though, so dont know that much.

Comment: s'pose these things are just plain `Object`'s right so wont have anything worth excluding.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to recent updates to JavaScript - we can solve this now:

```
function items(iterable) {
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
            for (key in iterable) {
                yield [key, iterable[key]];
            }
        }
    };
}

for (const [key, val] of items({"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5})) {
    console.log(key, val);
}
// a 3
// b 4
// c 5

for (const [key, val] of items(["a", "b", "c"])) {
    console.log(key, val);
}
// 0 a
// 1 b
// 2 c
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of `enumerate` in python, not what the OP asked

Comment: In JS an array is a list-like object where the keys are the indices. To help avoid confusion I've added an example of the items function with an object. @IuliusCurt FYI

Answer (score 0):

ubershmekel's answer makes use of lazy evaluation, compared to my answer below which uses eager evaluation. Lazy evaluation has many benefits which make it much more appropriate for performance reasons in some cases, but the transparency of eager evaluation can be a development speed boon that may make it preferable in other cases.

```
const keys = Object.keys;

const values = object =>
  keys(object).map(key => object[key]);

const items = object =>
  keys(object).map(key => [key, object[key]])


obj = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30};

keys(obj)   // ["a", "b", "c"]
values(obj) // [10, 20, 30]
items(obj)  // [["a", 10], ["b", 20], ["c", 30]]

items(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(k, v))
// a 10
// b 20
// c 30
```

Answer (score -3):

Not sure what you want to do but I guess Json.stringify will do something like that. See http://www.json.org/js.html