# Return Full JSON Object to Javascript from Service File

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a service file that is properly returning data in the following format

```
{"0":{"BUTTER": "PEANUT","TYPE":"ORGANIC"},
"1":{"BUTTER":"PEANUT","TYPE":"SPREAD"},
"2":{"BUTTER":"ALMOND","TYPE":"ORGANIC"}}
```

I am trying to get the key/value pair together into another JavaScript file via a function but I am having a little bit of trouble

This code returns just the butter key value:

```
butterList = Object.keys(butter).map(function(x) {return butter[x];});
```

Returns back

```
"PEANUT","PEANUT","ALMOND"
```

But how can I pass the entire key/value like

```
{"BUTTER:PEANUT,TYPE:ORGANIC}, {BUTTER:PEANUT,TYPE:SPREAD}, {BUTTER:ALMOND,TYPE:ORGANIC"}
```

Comment: What is your desired object looks?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I'm just trying to pass both the keys and values together. I can get them separately.

Comment: In your example above, what **exactly** is the `butter` object? How does it relate to the JSON at the top of your question?

Comment: A function with butter as a parameter and an ajax call to a service file that pulls from a SQL statement. butter can be renamed to anything, wouldn't matter

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. In your question above, you have `Object.keys(butter)...`. What is the value of `butter` here? Where does it come from?

Comment: and your expected answer value is supposed to be a string ?? (not an array ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : Replaced with the following function

```
function items(butter) {
 var i, arr = [];
 for(i in butter) {
   arr.push(butter[i]);
 }
 return JSON.stringify(arr);
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338685/how-can-i-replicate-pythons-dict-items-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
butterList = Object.keys(butter).map(function(x) {return {butter[x]}});
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I'm just trying to pass both the keys and values together. I can get them separately.

Comment: @datagoat sorry then i miss understood your context

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for ? -> {"0":"PEANUT","1":"PEANUT","2":"ALMOND"}

```js
const butter = { "0": { "BUTTER": "PEANUT", "TYPE": "ORGANIC" }
               , "1": { "BUTTER": "PEANUT", "TYPE": "SPREAD"  }
               , "2": { "BUTTER": "ALMOND", "TYPE": "ORGANIC" }
               };

butterList = Object
              .keys(butter)
              .reduce((a,c)=>{a[c] = butter[c]['BUTTER']; return a},{})

document.write( JSON.stringify ( butterList ))
// {"0":"PEANUT","1":"PEANUT","2":"ALMOND"}
```

or this ??  -> (string) = {"BUTTER:PEANUT,TYPE:ORGANIC},{BUTTER:PEANUT,TYPE:SPREAD},{BUTTER:ALMOND,TYPE:ORGANIC"}

```js
const butter = { "0": { "BUTTER": "PEANUT", "TYPE": "ORGANIC" }
               , "1": { "BUTTER": "PEANUT", "TYPE": "SPREAD"  }
               , "2": { "BUTTER": "ALMOND", "TYPE": "ORGANIC" }
               };
               
const butterList1 = Object.keys(butter)
                    .reduce((a,c,i,t)=>
                      {
                      let s = JSON.stringify(butter[c]).replace(/"/g,'')
                      if (i==0) s = `{"${s.substring(1)}`
                      if (i==(t.length-1)) s = `${s.substring(0,s.length-1)}"}`
                      a.push(s)
                      return a
                      },[])
                      .join(',');

document.write( butterList1 )
```

But I thing you only need this:

```
const butterList = Object.values(butter)
```

Comment: No, I can get the keys fine... I'm just trying to get the key and value pairs together passed

Comment: @datagoat  how that concatenate in an array ?

Comment: `{"BUTTER:PEANUT, TYPE:ORGANIC}, {BUTTER:PEANUT,TYPE:SPREAD}, {BUTTER: ALMOND, TYPE: ORGANIC"}`

Is what I'm trying to return

Comment: @datagoat with **no double quote inside**?? like `{"BUTTER":"PEANUT","TYPE":"ORGANIC"}, {"B"UTTER":"PEANUT","TYPE":"SPREAD"}, {"BUTTER":"ALMOND","TYPE":"ORGANIC"}`

Comment: @datagoat I have added a new anwser corresponding of your previous format

Comment: @datagoat  I have added a last case answer